# Error in reshape matrix - machine learning

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following problem when this code is executed:
I tred to make ths code work:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Convolution2D, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, GlobalAveragePooling2D
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.utils import np_utils
from sklearn import metrics
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
import tensorflow as tf

from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from keras.utils import to_categorical

num_rows = 13
num_columns = 87
num_channels = 1
seed = 2001

path = 'C:/Users/lione/OneDrive/Bureau/Lionel/LDK_360/Projets/Fexy-consign/Data/cleaned_dataset.xlsx'

featuresdf = pd.read_excel(path)

X = np.array(featuresdf.feature.tolist())
y = np.array(featuresdf.label.tolist())

kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=True, random_state=seed)
cvscores = []

X = X.reshape(X.shape[0], num_rows, num_columns, num_channels)

for train, test in kfold.split(X, y):



  le = LabelEncoder()
  yy = to_categorical(le.fit_transform(y))
  num_labels = yy.shape[1]
  num_labels = 5
  filter_size = 2

# Construct model
  model = Sequential()
  model.add(Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=2, input_shape=(num_rows, num_columns, num_channels), activation='relu'))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=1))
  model.add(Dropout(0.5))

  model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=2, activation='relu'))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=1))
  model.add(Dropout(0.5))

  model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=2, activation='relu'))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=1))
  model.add(Dropout(0.5))

  model.add(Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=2, activation='relu'))
  model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=1))
  model.add(Dropout(0.5))
  model.add(GlobalAveragePooling2D())

  model.add(Dense(num_labels, activation='softmax'))
  # Compile model
  model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
  #Fit the model
  train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X[train], yy[train]))
  model.fit(X[train], yy[train], epochs=100, batch_size=32, verbose=2)
 # model.fit(train_data, epochs=100, batch_size=32, verbose=2)
  # evaluate the model
  scores = model.evaluate(X[test], yy[test], verbose=2)
  print("%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
  cvscores.append(scores[1] * 100)

print("%.2f%% (+/- %.2f%%)" % (numpy.mean(cvscores), numpy.std(cvscores)))
```

Error:

```
cannot reshape array of size 2001 into shape (2001,13,87,1)
```

I tried many solutions but with no success...

Comment: If the error was in the `X = X.reshape(X.shape[0],...` line (you SHOULD have told us!), you could omit the rest of the code.  Then examine `X`.  What's its nature.  from the error we can guess it's a list with 2001 elements, but what are the elements.  Before `trying meny solutions`, focus on understanding the problem.  Random trial-and-error fixes probably won't work!

Comment: Hi, sorry not to have specified it . After examing X, X is initialy (before executing the code), X.shape = (2001,13,87)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I solved the problem. X was indeed the problem....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`featuresdf.feature.tolist()` will probably make a [1d list](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.tolist.html).

Check the `feature` column of the `featuresdf` input to see how many elements are in this column (and check its rank).

If it has 2001 elements, then when you use `reshape`, the dimensions of the reshaped array must ultimately have the same number of elements.

The reshaped array you're trying to make has 2001 x 13 x 87 x 1 = 2263131 elements. That's not going to work, because you're starting with 2001 elements.

Interestingly, the prime factors of 2001 are: 3, 23, and 29. Multiplying 3 x 29 = 87, which is the length of one of the four dimensions in your reshaped array.

Perhaps you have a typo and need to resize a 2001-element list to an array that is 87 x 23, and not 87 x 13? (And definitely not 2001 x 87 x 13 x 1.)

Comment: Thanks. I solved the problem thanks to your recommendation !!!! Have a nice day....